# Linux and Windows stopped booting after I cloned them to a different drive

Tags: linux, windows, boot, partitioning

I've found myself in a peculiar spot. I have 3 drives:

- Drive_1: empty
- Drive_2: contains Windows 10
- Drive_3: contains Kali Linux

I decided to 'move' data from one drive to another by cloning: I booted from a special 'maintenance' USB stick and used EaseUS Partition Master app to clone one drive onto another. So I moved data from Drive_2 to Drive_1 and from Drive_3 to Drive_2. Then I (physically) removed Drive_3. So now I only have two drives:

- Drive_1: contains Windows 10
- Drive_2: contains Kali Linux

The problem is that none of them would boot now. All data is still there and they're partitioned correctly but they just won't boot. The only way to boot into Windows 10 is by using that 'maintenance' USB stick which has a function to 'Find and boot Windows' and the only way to access data on Linux drive is by using Live USB.

Does anyone have some ideas how can I make those drives bootable again? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The boot information no longer matches, and because you're dual-booting Windows and Linux, you can't use `BootRec` _(the normal way to fix Windows boot issues)_ to fix the Windows boot issue since doing so will overwrite GRUB; you'll need to use a Linux program to rebuild the BCD Store for Windows. For the Linux boot issue, someone else will need to chime in.

Comment: Have you changed the boot order in UEFI?

Comment: @Robert I'm seeing stange things when selecting a boot drive, for example a drive that now contains Linux still says 'Windows Boot <something>'

Comment: If you are using Kali as a general-purpose operating system, you are _Doing It Wrong._ Read their FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what distribution of linux you are using and it's also unclear what bootloader you are using? could you please add these details?

As you have not given enough information it's hard to help with your specific needs, but if you are using GRUB + Ubuntu, you likely need to boot from a live CD / installation media, chroot into the system and re-install GRUB. For example;

http://subinsb.com/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-using-a-ubuntu-live-cd/

In fact, chroot'ing into the system is likely what you need to do, regardless of the distribution -- but you are going to want to consult your linux distribution's documentation, wiki or support forums for that information (or provide more info here).

the steps can differ, depending on the distro + bootloader.

EDIT: As you've now verified it's Kali Linux

https://goacademy.io/reinstall-grub-on-kali-linux/

Comment: I'm using Kali Linux, I've just updated the main post to mention that. Thank you!

Comment: https://goacademy.io/reinstall-grub-on-kali-linux/